# HTML table content: how to show part of content in new line if the line is lengthy

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML content like

```
<Table style="width=100px;">
<tr>
<td>
KEY1:Value1 Key2:Value2
</td>
<tr>
<Table>
```

Now if my td content is longer than the TD width, it should show like

Key1: value1
Key2: value2

Note: this should be applicable only if the content length is higher than the TD width
Also, this is needed for IE6

Comment: would the downvoter care to specify why it was done so?

Comment: Really this question was asked SO many times that you should consider better googling instead of duplicating. Though I upvoted the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set table-layout:fixed for table and  word-wrap:break-word in the td.

```
table{
    width:100px;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

td{
    word-wrap:break-word ;
}
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x0fr8ur6/)

Comment: Share the result here. I didn't try in IE6 :P

Comment: aravind: i tried this is in IE8 first 
the same fiddle code but with some additions like border, width etc
seems to be breaking.. any suggestions?

Comment: Like <table style="width:10px;" border="1">

Comment: And what was the result you obtained after adding border?

Comment: sorry if I did not state my scenario correctly, the KEY VALUE text can be dynamic

Comment: Can u provide the exact details on the problem you are facing? I am not sure what I need to solve here